# Twig doesn't throw exceptions

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am using symfony 2.3 with twig 1.0.* Twig doesn't throw any errors when undeclared variables are displayed. All errors are ignored.

For example, I have any undefined variable '`test`' I can do the following and no errors are displayed just blank text.

```
{{ test }}
{{ test.do() }}
{{ test.test2 }}
```

Is there a setting to turn this back on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the `strict_variables` option of twig. In a symfony standard installation the twig configuration defaults to

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
```

which means it depends on the debug option of the kernel. In prod environment this should be false of course, but in the dev environment it should default to true and twig should throw a exception. If the kernel debug is not true in dev, check your `web/app_dev.php` file. It should initialize the `AppKernel` with the following line.

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

Comment: "In prod environment this should be false of course" - I don't understand this part. Doesn't this mean that a bug would be silently hidden? I understand this should be true in dev environment to catch the bug there first. But if it slips through, there is no chance to catch it in the production logs. Or am I missing a point?